# Почему нужно возвращать ссылку на объект iostream

Tags: c++, ооп

При перегрузке оператора вывода, зачем возвращать ссылку на объект iostream, а не просто объект iostream?

```
class A
{
public:
int m_a;
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream left, A a)
{
cout << a.m_a;
return left;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Объекты класса `std::ostream` не являются копируемыми. У этого класса конструктор копирования и копирующий оператор присваивания определены как удалённые. Поэтому если из определения оператора вы уберете ссылку на поток, то компилятор сообщит об ошибке.